# Control Kivy Slider with Keyboard buttons?

Tags: python, keyboard, kivy, slider

I have developed a Kivy Desktop App with some buttons and sliders to control a robot. I want to employ keyboard controls for this purpose. But I can't seem to find a method to control slider value through the keyboard. My purpose is to control this kivy slider through 'w' and 's' keyboard keys such that when I press 'w' slider value goes up while pressing 's' does the opposite. Is there any way to solve this problem? A small written code would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using keyboard events:

```
class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Window.bind(on_key_down=self._keydown)
        Window.bind(on_key_up=self._keyup)
        return Label(text='Hi')

    def _keydown(self, window, key, scancode, codepoint, modifiers):
        print('keydown:')
        print('\tkey:',key)
        print('\tscancode:', scancode)
        print('\tcodepoint:', codepoint)
        print('\tmodifiers:', modifiers)


    def _keyup(self, window, key, scancode):
        print('keyup:')
        print('\tkey:',key)
        print('\tscancode:', scancode)

TestApp().run()
```

Comment: That's great but how can this be integrated with slider functionality?

Comment: In the `_keydown()` or `_keyup()` methods you can set the `value` or `value_normalized` properties of the `Slider`.

Comment: oh thats great. Thankss